# Axis2 temp file

Tags: apache-axis

I am using the Axis2 1.6. On each request client is genetrating the temp files and thus leading to disk space problem.

Can I request some one to pint me to some article how this problem can be addressed.

Regards,
Amber

Comment: The axis2 library doesn't create temporary files as far as I'm aware. Do you understand where these files are coming from?

Comment: The files come from the Axis2 modules (.mar) files being extracted for use.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue with Axis2 1.6.3. I'm using the [Addressing](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/modules/addressing/index.html) module (`org.apache.axis2:addressing:1.6.3:jar:classpath-module`).

My entire shaded JAR was getting copied into the temp directory and not deleted if the Java process ever crashed, so disk usage grew unchecked.

My approach to solving this was to manually register the module with Axis2, instead of letting it automatically register, so it skips writing the temp JAR to disk.

I used the logic from Axis2's `ModuleDeployer.deploy()` and `DeploymentEngine.addNewModule()`.

### Old code which creates temp files

```js
ConfigurationContext context = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(null, null);

MyExampleStub myExampleStub = new MyExampleStub(context, mySoapUri);
myExampleStub._getServiceClient().engageModule("addressing");
```

### New code which doesn't create temp files

```js
ConfigurationContext context = ConfigurationContextFactory.createDefaultConfigurationContext();
AxisConfiguration axisConfiguration = context.getAxisConfiguration();

AxisModule addressing = new AxisModule("addressing");
addressing.setParent(axisConfiguration);
addressing.setModuleClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
InputStream moduleXmlInputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/module.xml");
new ModuleBuilder(moduleXmlInputStream, addressing, axisConfiguration).populateModule();
DeploymentEngine.addNewModule(addressing, axisConfiguration);

MyExampleStub myExampleStub = new MyExampleStub(context, mySoapUri);
myExampleStub._getServiceClient().engageModule("addressing");
```

Now I still see the expected `<wsa:To>`, `<wsa:MessageID>`, and `<wsa:Action>` elements in my outgoing request `<Header>`, but my temp directory doesn't contain any `axis2-tmp-6160203768737879650.tmp` directories or `axis2-tmp-6160203768737879650.tmp.lck` files.

Answer (score 0):

This seams to be a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3919) fixed by version 1.7.0.

Comment: 1.7.0 is not yet released, would appreciate a fix for this on 1.5.4, or any workaround in the code for this besides deleting the temp folder contents.